# Watson API in Android

Tags: android, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I am new to this API (Watson API) and my Android experience is kind a rusty so please bear with me if I cannot catch up with your terminologies/ideas right away.

According to Watson API guide
(you can check it in here https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk)

> "Once you have credentials, copy config.properties.example to
>   src/test/resources/config.properties, and fill them in as necessary."

Currently I am stuck in this area. Where can I find that config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to copy `config.properties` if you want to run the tests cases. If you just want to use the sdk you just need to specify the service credentials using the `setUsernameAndPassword()` method.

For example:

```
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");
```

---

In order to use the IBM Watson APIs in Android, I would suggest you look at the [android-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk). The repository [README](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk#microphone-input-stream) has an example of how to transcribe audio from the microphone using the Speech to Text API.

Comment: This dependency link is not working anyone have its correct link?. I did also check on its Git Hub page.

Comment: You will have to build the jar from the code using Gradle because the dependency is not on maven yet.